# Dimension of the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ as almost complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, complex-manifolds, almost-complex

I have already shown that the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ is a complex manifold by checking the required properties of the transition maps. Since every complex manifold is an almost complex manifold, $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ is also an almost complex manifold. I wonder what is its dimension. I have proved that almost complex manifolds always have even dimension. But how can I determine the dimension of the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ as an almost complex manifold? And how can I prove this answer? It would be great if someone could help me with this proof.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Well, if you've figured out the transition maps, you must know what the charts are? What is the dimension of the Euclidean space you are using for the charts?

Comment: I have constructed chart maps from $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$. Does that mean that the complex projective space has complex dimension $n$ and real dimension $2n$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

An almost complex manifold is a real smooth manifold $M$ with a bundle map
$$
J: TM\rightarrow TM
$$
such that $J^2=-id$.  When you ask what is the dimension of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ as an almost complex manifold, what you're asking is what is its dimension as a real manifold.  If $M$ is a complex manifold of complex dimension $n$, then the dimension of $M$ as a real manifold is $2n$.  In other words,
$$
\dim_{\mathbb{R}}M=2\dim_{\mathbb{C}}M
$$
Since $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{CP}^n=n$, then $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{CP}^n=2n$.